# How do I get my program to print 'Even' after it has separated a user input list of numbers

Tags: python

I'm new to python and had a question about the way my program is working. I want the program to print *True*, after it has separated the list into even numbers. However it keeps returning `false`, even when the elements are even numbers. I would appreciate any tips on how to go about doing this, as well as any suggestions for writing simpler code.

```
a =  input('Enter numbers seperated by a comma: ')
userList = [int(i) for i in a.split(',')]
userList = [n for n in userList if n % 2 == 0]
print(userList)    
if len(userList) % 2 == 0:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Comment: Your program will print the list of even numbers, then either 'True' or 'False'. Do you want it to print the word 'Even'? It's not quite clear what you want here. Can you clarify.

Comment: Hi! @wstk thank you for replying. Ah sorry I want it to print the word 'True', however it keeps giving me False i will edit my question.

Comment: So if the list of even number, is an *even length* you want it to print 'True'?

Comment: `if len(userList) % 2 == 0:` should be `if len(userList) > 0:`

Comment: @wstk yes if the length is even i want it to print even, and if it is odd i want it to return false, when i tried running it it jsut printed out false.

Comment: I think your code works fine. Try it with input '1,2,3,4,5'. This means `userList = [2,4]` which is an even length. When i run you code, I get 'True' printed...

Comment: @Nick sorry no, this makes everything true

Comment: @CSnoob it's not clear what you want then? Do you only want to print true if there are an even number of even numbers? or ???

Comment: @wstk that is so strange, I tried that and it still gives me false. maybe something on my end

Comment: @Nick after the list has seperated the even numbers from the numbers entered by the user, i want the program to evaluate the length of the output and print true or false

Comment: @CSnoob but true or false based on what criteria? if it should be true if the length of `userList` is even (i.e. there were an even number of even numbers) then your code works fine as is.

Comment: @CSnoob - so when you `print(UserList)` you can see a list, for example `[2,4,6,8]`. And then it prints False?And the code is *exactly* as you have posted?

Comment: https://rextester.com/UXB11511

Comment: it must be something on my end then, Im not sure why it keeps printing false, if you both are getting true ill assume it works.

Comment: Ah i fixed it, thank you both for your help!

Comment: @CSnoob - what was it? (i am curious...)

Comment: @wstk wrong inputs on my end and I forgot to put back in the % after trying nicks suggestion.